# Run VBA code in Excel based on a cell value change by a function

Tags: vba, excel

Kindly I need help after trying for hours myself.

I have this code to run a code base on a cell value change, but works only if I type myself the change.

I need to be automatic with the function I have inside the cell, but I can get it right.

This is the code I have now that works well manually:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("D10").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Anything that I should add to make it automatic with the formula inside?

Comment: This is pretty vague... Is A1 the cell that is being changed by the formula in your example or is it the cell with the formula in it? A little more information will help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one since there is no built in worksheet event that triggers when a particular cell has a value change due to a formula. There is, however, a Worksheet.Calculate event that could be used.

First we make a global string variable. This is a variable that is declared outside of a subroutine or function. It will hold it's value between executions of subroutines and functions. So we will declare it, and then set it to the value of A1 when A1 is changed.

```
Dim lastValue As String
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("A1").Value <> lastValue Then
        lastValue = Range("A1").Value
        Range("D10").ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

`lastValue` here is our Global that will hold the last known value of `A1`. When `worksheet.calculate` is triggered it will compare that value against `A1` to see if it's changed, if it is then it executes your code to clear the contents of `D1`

Instead of a Global you could also just stick that last known value of A1 into a Cell somewhere too. Then do you comparison to that. The advantage of using a cell over a global variable, is that the cell value will hold it's value even if you close and reopen the sheet. So, depending on your needs, it may be a better option:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    lastValue = Range("Z10").value
    If Range("A1").Value <> lastValue Then
        Range("Z10").value = Range("A1").Value
        Range("D10").ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

Where Range `Z10` is the spot that holds the last known value.

Lastly I reduced your code to clear contents of `D10` to a single line. Anytime you see `Something.Select` and then in the next line see `Selection.DoSomething` you can just get rid of that `Select/Selection` bit. Selecting a cell is generally something that only a human needs to do to interact with the sheet. VBA can do whatever it likes to cells without have to `Select` them.